# Android Device Monitor / DDMS does not show threads from device

Tags: android, android-device-monitor

I'm trying to debug a thrid party app like shown here [Android Reverse Engineering: Debugging Smali in Smalidea](https://crosp.net/blog/software-development/mobile/android/android-reverse-engineering-debugging-smali-using-smalidea/) . The problem is that the Android Device Monitor / DDMS is not showing any threads and the "Update threads" button is disabled.

[image: Android Device Monitor]

Does anyone has an idea why that is the case?

I tried different physical devices and emulators (I'm using Win10) and even used the new profiler from Android Studio (also just showing "no processes to debug"). USB debugging is enabled and I can access all devices via adb from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is: The emulator (or the physical device) seems to needed to be rooted. Therefore only emulators images named "Google API" and not having a "Google Play Symbol" in the "Play Store Support column" are debugable.